# Using a single xcode file for multiple projects

Tags: ios, swift

I haven’t tried this before but wanted to know how it happens. Suppose I have an Xcode file for my project called ‘Project A’. Now I want to make another project with the same features as that of ‘Project A’ for a project called ‘project B’. But for ‘project B’, I don’t want to make a different Xcode file but rather want to incorporate the changes in ‘project A’ itself so that when I run the same project, I’ll be able to run project A or project B as per my need. How can I achieve this…?

Comment: Cocoapods, make your own pod :)

Comment: I'm sorry @J. Doe. Would you mind explaining in a bit more detail..:) I didn't get you...:)

Comment: Hmm, search for Cocoapods. It is a dependency manager. You can create your own frameworks (just some .swift files). Than, in each and every project you can include that file. It is to much work to explain it here,there are plenty of results on google when searching for "Create pod cocoapods"

Comment: Ok @J. Doe. Thanks..

Comment: Another possibility is move the code/file you wish to share into a Framework target. I've done this with everything from UI elements, classes, whatever. Then you use `import` just like you do with `UIKit` or `StoreKit`. Even better - pull your  Framework and *both* Projects into an Xcode workspace and work on all three at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on your project, Goto General > Targets.

Right click on your project Target and select Duplicate.

You will get to choose between iPad and continue to duplicate for iPhone.

Going ahead in each new/existing file, you can choose which target it belongs to and keep doing your development. If you exclude the file from an target, it will not contribute to that app's size.

You can also keep your future files in both Targets depending on your needs.